# How to give more EditText fields a one line feeling

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-edittext

I have 4 edit-text fields in my code where the user has to insert 4 digits. I'd like to have the 4 fields to be connected to each other, just like it would be for one text field. Means, that if I've entered the first digit it should jump directly to the 2nd edit-text and so on. Deleting it should go back from 4 to 1 without having the user to pick each field and delete the inserted value

How can I manage that?

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/number_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numberone"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edit_text"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_h"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/numbertwo"
            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numbertwo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edit_text"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_h"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/numberthree"
            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numberthree"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edit_text"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_h"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/numberfour"
            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numberfour"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/safe_edit_text"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/safe_edit_text_h"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/btn_confirmcode"
            />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Note that there are many existing OTP-style widgets. https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=otp lists a bunch (unfortunately, along with other libraries that happen to have "otp" in their descriptions...).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would catch the input event for each of the edit text and check if user has deleted some text or inserted it. After that you can tell the program to get the focus of next/previous edit text and so on. For example;

```
 binding.editText2.doAfterTextChanged { 
       if (it?.length!! > 0) {
           //change focus to the next edittext
           binding.editText3.requestFocus()
       } else if (it?.length == 0) {
           //change focus to the previous edit text
           binding.editText1.requestFocus()
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving this here for anyone with the same problem:

```
 for(i in 1..4) {
                        val layoutID = this.resources
                                .getIdentifier("editText$i","id",this.activity!!.packageName)
                        val currentEditText = view.findViewById<EditText>(layoutID)

                        currentEditText.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{

                            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                                Log.e("p0?.length",p0?.length.toString())
                                if (p0?.length!! > 0) {
                                    //change focus to the next edittext
                                    if(i in 1..3){
                                        val layoutIDnext = this.resources
                                                .getIdentifier("editText"+(i+1),
                                                        "id",
                                                        this.activity!!.packageName)
                                        val nextEditText = view.findViewById<EditText>(layoutIDnext)
                                        nextEditText.requestFocus()
                                    }

                                } else if (p0?.length == 0) {
                                    //change focus to the previous edit text

                                    if(i in 2..4) {
                                        val layoutIdbefore = this.resources.getIdentifier("editText"+(i-1),
                                                "id",
                                                this.activity!!.packageName)
                                        val lastEditText = view.findViewById<EditText>(layoutIdbefore)
                                        lastEditText.requestFocus()

                                        currentEditText.setOnKeyListener { _, _, keyEvent ->
                                            if(keyEvent.keyeditText == KeyEvent.KEYeditText_DEL) {
                                                lastEditText.requestFocus()
                                            }
                                            return@setOnKeyListener false
                                        }

                                    }

                                }}

                            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                                }

                            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

                            }
                        })
                    }
```